# Copy multiple files to one dir with parallel

Tags: bash, command-line, cp, gnu-parallel, brace-expansion

I'm using the following script to copy multiple files into one folder:

```
{ echo $BASE1; echo $BASE2; echo $BASE3; } | parallel cp -a {} $DEST
```

Is there any way to use only one echo $BASE with brace expansion?

I mean something like this:

```
{ echo $BASE{1..3} } | parallel cp -a {} $DEST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array:

```
BASES[0]=...
BASES[1]=...
BASES[2]=...
# or BASES+=(...)
# or BASES=(foo bar baz)
echo "${BASES[@]}" | parallel cp -a {} $DEST
```

To make it safer (spaces and newlines in the variable in particular), something like this should work more reliably:

```
printf "%s\0" "${BASES[@]}" | parallel -0 cp -a {} "$DEST"
```

Note: arrays aren't in POSIX, this works with current versions of bash and ksh though.

Comment: Arrays and portability...

Comment: @damianjb In zsh, you can save a bit of typing: `print -N $BASES | parallel -0 cp -a {} $DEST`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` instead of `echo`, to get the newlines you need:

```
 env printf "%s\n" $BASE{1..3} | parallel cp -a {} $DEST
```